# How to combine numbers inside an arithmetic operation input before and after the sign for example "+" or "-"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I apologies if this question has already been answered but I search for this and couldn't find the answer for it. maybe I am writing the question in a weird way but I'm new so I'm sorry about that.
there are many problems with my code and I think its very inefficient because if the input of `a + b` for example was `-25 + 2` then a will only read `operation[1]` which will be `2`, and when I run it, it will not give me the answer I want.
To cut a long story short, is there a way to enter a line of code that combines all numbers before the sign?
for example a = all the numbers before (-) and b =  all numbers after the sign (-).
this is a sample of the code I'm trying to write:

```
operation = input('Enter an arithemtic operation: ')
print(operation)
operation = operation.replace(" ", "")
if len(operation) == 3:
    a = int(operation[0])
    b = int(operation[2])
    sign2 = operation[1]
    if(sign2 == '+'):
        sum = a + b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '-'):
        sum = a - b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '*'):
        sum = a * b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '/'):
        sum = a / b
        print(round(sum, 3))

elif len(operation) == 4:
    a = int(operation[1]) * -1
    b = int(operation[3])
    sign1 = operation[0]
    sign2 = operation[2]
    if(sign2 == '+'):
        sum = a + b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '-'):
        sum = a - b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '*'):
        sum =  a * b
        print(sum)
    elif(sign2 == '/'):
        sum = a / b
        print(round(sum, 3))

    


else:
    print('input invalid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this is wrong, because maybe I'm not understanding the question right, but can't you just use `eval` to get the value of the arithmetic operation?

```py
example_input = "1 + 2 * 3"

print(eval(example_input))

## OUTPUT:
# 7
```

This will work as long as the expression entered in the `example_input` is a valid python expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression (Regex) from the re library, it is a little complex but if you learn the basics it will help you a lot. Check my suggestion below

```
import re

def foo():
    operation = input("Enter Operation: ")
    match = re.findall(r"([+-]\d+)\b\s*([+-])\s*(\d+)", operation) # This line finds the three components of the equation/operation (LHS, sign & RHS) and excludes any spaces in-between
    lft = int(match[0][0])
    rght = int(match[0][-1])
    sign = match[0][1]
    if sign == "+":
        return lft + rght
    elif sign == "-":
        return lft - rght
    else:
        return False
```

Generally you should find a lot of help for regex related stuff, but it is worth learning a little about it. Sentdex has a really nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZyAn2TW7GY) about this.

[image]

Comment: when i try to run this code, for some reason in the console it doesn't print ("Enter Operation: ") is there something i should add to my program to read it? a plug in or something?

Comment: This is a function so when you run the code it defines the function, allowing you to call it at any time by typing the name of the function (in this case you type `foo()` ) and it should run.

Comment: If you want to run the code as a one time thing just copy everything from after the line `def foo():`

Comment: i ran it, gave me same problem i was having,
 `
Enter Operation: -6+7 
=
13
`

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your problem. Check the picture added to the end of the answer. Is this what you are trying to achieve (Inputting an equation say, `-6 + 7`, and get the result of that equation, `1`)? If yes, then copy the code again, I adjusted a minor thing.

Comment: yeah i did, and it works however, it does not fit the problem im trying to answer since its only solving -a+b it does not allow for a+b or a*b. i added to the code, return lft / rght but it did not work. not sure why. it says outside the range of [0][0]